# N-th homology group of X#Y where X and Y are connected N-varieties.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Does a formula exist that returns the $N$-th homology group of given the $N$-th homology group of $X$ and $Y$? In this case, $X$ and $Y$ are connected $N$-varieties and $X\#Y$ is their connected sum.

Comment: maybe you can use Mayer–Vietoris sequence

Comment: $\#$does this mean connected sum??

Comment: @Andrey Ryabichev I've tried that, but I come up with nonsense.

Comment: @Anubhav.K: Correct.

Comment: @Luz $'N'$ is the top dimension?? What about $X,Y$ could you please edit your qes properly?? there are lots of ambiguity

Comment: There are several posts in this site about the homology of connected sums of manifolds. Have you looked at them?